# How much can two polynomials agree on?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials

Let $f(x,y)$ be a polynomial in $\mathbf R[x, y]$ such that $f(x, x^3) = 0$ for all $1< x< 2$.

> **Question.** Then is it necessary that $f(x, x^3) = 0$ for all $x$?

(As pointed out by @dvix in the comments, this question has answer YES. The reason is that $f(x, x^3)$ is a single variabel polynomial vanishing on infinitely many points, and hence must be identically zero).

More generally what I want to know is the following:

> **Question.** Suppose $X\subseteq \mathbf R^n$ is an irreducible affine variety and $f\in \mathbf R[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$ be a polynomial which vanishes on an open subset of $X$.
>   Then is it forced that $f$ vanishes on all of $X$. Or at least on all smooth points of $X$?

Here "open" is with respect to Euclidean topology.

Comment: Let $n$ be the degree (in $x$) of $g(x)=f(x,x^3)$. If $g$ vanishes at $n+1$ distinct points, then $g \equiv 0$.

Comment: Ah! That's right! Somehow this argument didn't click. Thanks. Do you also know an answer to the general question I posed?

Comment: I don't see how to prove your general question but my intuition is that it's true.  My idea is to look at the vanishing set of f.  It is closed, and by your assumption about the open subset of X, it should have the same dimension as X or bigger dimension.  Then from the fact that X is irreducible, the vanishing set of f should contain all of X.  Hopefully someone gives a precise answer!

Comment: Not sure about that one, and don't know that it follows from (something like) the first statement.

Comment: @BalarkaSen I don't think that argument works because they don't mean Zariski open they mean open in the Euclidean topology.

Comment: @CJD AH, I see. That was confusing.

Comment: I think dxiv's argument works only if $X$ is a rational variety, in which case one can parametrize it by a rational isomorphism $g : \Bbb R^n \to X$, and then compose with $f$ to get $f \circ g : \Bbb R^n \to X \to \Bbb R$, zero set of which is zero set of a locally polynomial map (which you get after cross-multiplication to cancel denominators near the zero set), and so the problem reduces to asking if an open subset of $\Bbb R^n$ can be zero set of a polynomial (that isn't true unless it's identically zero: that's a "Taylor series" proof)

Comment: @BalarkaSen Can you frame your comment as an answer (and if possible please give the relevant definitions; I am a noob at AG). Also, to show that a polynomial $R^n\to  R$ vanishing on an open set is identically one can avoid Taylor series. Say $f(x, y)\in R[x, y]$ vanishes in the open square $(0, 1)\times (0, 1)$. Then for each $y\in (0, 1)$, the single variable polynomial $f(x, y)$ has all it's coefficients $0$. The coefficients of this polynomials are themselves singe variable polynomials, which, as just mentioned, vanish for each input from $(0, 1)$ and hence each coeff is identically zero.

Comment: @caffeinemachine That's a very nice proof! Regular/polynomial functions are really quite rigid. Also I don't think my comment is quite an answer to your question; pretty much all it says if you can find a rational parametrization for your variety $X$, like for $y = x^3$ you can find $(t, t^3)$, then the same argument of drxiv pushes through. Likely people will come up with better answers assuming less hypothesis. (I'm equally nooby at algebraic geometry, honestly)

Comment: (So the algebraic essence of your proof is that $\Bbb R[x_1, \cdots, x_n] = \Bbb R[x_n][x_1, \cdots, x_{n-1}]$, so it's a polynomial in $x_1, \cdots, x_{n-1}$ with coefficients being polynomials of a single variable $x_n$. Project the open set to a coordinate hyperplane, it's open, and by induction the coefficients are zero for each fixed $x_n$-coordinate. Then use the one variable degree magic. Nice.)

Comment: @BalarkaSen Yes that is exactly what I was trying to convey.

Comment: This will move the discussion away from the question you asked, but I think there is a merit to this proof in the sense that it generalizes to an identity theorem for multivariable analytic functions (I only just realized this). Look up the Weierstrass preparation theorem if you have not heard of it; it says upto a unit one can write any power series in $n$ variables as a polynomial in one of the variables with coefficients being a power series in $n-1$ other variables

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the following, when we write $\dim$, we mean dimension as a topological space, and when we write varieties, we mean schemes of finite type over a field, and when we write $\dim$ of a scheme, we mean dimension of the associated topological space.

Let $U\subset X(\Bbb R)$ be the open set on which $f$ vanishes. $f=0$ is a closed set in $X$, so if $X$ is reduced and $U$ is of dimension $\dim X$, then $f$ must be identically zero ($\{f=0\}$ is a closed set containing $U$, so $\dim \{f=0\} \geq \dim U=\dim X$, and the only closed subset of an irreducible, reduced variety of dimension $\dim X$ is $X$).

It is important that $\dim U = \dim X$: it may happen that $\dim U < \dim X$, such as the case when $X = V(x^2-y^2z)$ - here, $X$ is two-dimensional, irreducible, and reduced, but it is possible to pick a $U\subset X(\Bbb R)$ which is open but has dimension 1: consider $X(\Bbb R)\cap ((-1,1)\times(-1,1)\times(-2,-1)).$ If $U$ consists entirely of smooth points, you are ensured that $\dim U=\dim X$, by the implicit function theorem.

Comment: That's a nice answer!  So for example if you take f = x in your V(x^2 - y^2 z) example, you have a polynomial which vanishes on an open (in the Euclidean topology) subset of the irreducible variety but which doesn't vanish on all of the irreducible variety.

Comment: Do you know if a smoothness hypothesis is also necessary if we're working over the complex numbers instead of the real numbers?

Comment: @KReiser Thanks for the answer. At least now I know that the speculation is true in a sufficiently general setting. Unfortunately I do not know enough to fully understand your answer. Can you please provide a reference from where I can understand the proof of the fact that "the only closed subset of an irreducible, reduced variety $X$ of dimension $\dim X$ is $X$"?

Comment: @KReiser And if possible can you mention the definition of a reduced variety in your answer itself. Thanks.

Comment: The definition of reduced is a definition you should encounter pretty early in your algebraic geometry life, and I would encourage you to look it up: a reduced scheme has no nilpotent elements in the structure sheaf (what this means for affine schemes is that the coordinate ring has no nilpotents). As far as the claim about irreducibles, this is also fairly straightforwards: suppose $X_1\subset X$ is a proper closed subset of dimension $\dim X$. Then $X_1\cup \overline{(X_1^c)}$ is a nontrivial decomposition of $X$ into a union of two proper closed subsets, which contradicts irreducibility.

Comment: @KReiser Thanks for your response.  In your comment about irreducibles, how do you know that the closure of the complement of X_1 is not all of X?  I don't see where you use the hypothesis about the dimension, so I assume this is where it is used (also since the claim is false for smaller dimension closed subsets).  (I also don't see how the negative z-axis plays a special role in the complex case.)

Comment: If $\overline{X_1^c}$ is all of $X$, then the definition of dimension by length of chains of proper inclusions of irreducible closed subsets gives that $\dim X = \dim X_1+1$, contradicting the assumption. As for the complex case, you are correct - I was hasty when I wrote that comment. The smooth locus of a complex variety is connected, and any open neighborhood of a singular point contains a smooth point in the complex case, so $\dim U=\dim X$ automatically.

Comment: @KReiser Can you please have a look at this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2878158/polynomial-vanishing-on-an-open-subset-of-an-irreducible-variety-follow-up-ques Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This can be proven using basic linear algebra concepts.

Consider a generic polynomial $p(x)$ of degree $n$:

$$p(x) = \sum_{i=0}^n a_i x^i.$$

Suppose that you don't know the coefficient $a_i$ (they are $n+1$), but you know the value of the polynomial for $n+1$ different values of $x$, let's say $$p(x_j) = y_j.$$

for $j=1, \ldots, n+1.$
Under this assumption, you can try to find the coefficients $a_i$ by solving the following linear system:

$$\begin{cases}
a_0x_1^0 + a_1x_1^1 + \ldots + a_nx_1^n & = & y_1\\
a_0x_2^0 + a_1x_2^1 + \ldots + a_nx_2^n & = & y_2\\
\ldots \\
a_0x_{n+1}^0 + a_1x_{n+1}^1 + \ldots + a_nx_{n+1}^n & = & y_{n+1}\\
\end{cases}.$$

It can be easily proven that the square matrix of this linear system

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & x_1 & x_1^2 & \ldots & x_{1}^n \\
1 & x_2 & x_2^2 & \ldots & x_{2}^n \\
\ldots\\
1 & x_{n+1} & x_{n+1}^2 & \ldots & x_{n+1}^n
\end{bmatrix}$$

is a [Vandermonde matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix), which is invertible **if and only if** all $x_j$s are different.

Suppose now that for all (the different) $x_j$s, the value of the polynomial is $y_j = 0$. Then, the unique solution of the linear system (which now is homogeneous), is given by:

$$a_0 = a_1 = \ldots = a_n = 0.$$

Now, if $p(x) = 0$ for $x \in I$, where $I$ is an uncountable set, then you can always find $n+1$ points $x_j$ inside $I$ such that $p(x_j) = 0 (=y_j)$, implying that $a_0 = a_1 = \ldots = a_n = 0.$
Therefore, $p(x) = 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I think this shows why the fact that $f(x, x^3)=0$ for $1< x< 2$ implies that $f(x, x^3)=0$ for all $x$. That was made clear by @dvix's comment. A short proof can be given by using the fact that if $f(x)\in R[x]$ vanishes as $a$, then $x-a$ divides $f$. By a little reasoning one can further say that if $f$ vanishes on $a_1, \ldots, a_n$, then $(x-a_1)\cdots (x-a_n)$ divides $f$. So $f$ cannot vanish on more than its degree many points.

Comment: @caffeinemachine I know, this is just an alternative proof. Specifically, I hope it is easier to understand for a wider audience since it just uses linear algebra basic concepts.